# Find the one-dimensional sufficient statistics of i.i.d random variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given $T_1,\ldots, T_n$ are i.i.d random variables with pdf $\ f_{T}(t|\theta) = (\theta+1)t^{\theta}I_{(0,1)}(t)$. Find the one-dimensional sufficient statistics.

**My attempt:** We have: $f(\overline{t}|\theta) = (\theta+1)^n(t_1\ldots t_n)^\theta\prod_{i=1}^{n} I_{(0,1)}(t_i) $. Thus if we let $t_1\ldots t_n = t$, then we have:  $g(t|theta) = (\theta+1)^nt^\theta$ and $h(\overline{t}) = I_{(0,1)}(t_{(1)})$ where $\ t_{(1)} = min\left\{t_1,t_2,\ldots, t_n\right\}$. Therefore, by Factorization Theorem, the one-dimensional sufficient statistic is  $\ t_1\ldots t_n$

**My question:** Is the solution above correct? I'm skeptical a bit since it's quite simple.

Comment: Note that $\prod_{i=1}^n I_{(0,1)} (t_i) \neq  I_{(0,1)}(t_{(1)}) $. 

And what all these transformations for? From the very beginning, the function $f(\bar t |\theta)$ is already in product form: 
$$
f(T_1,\ldots,T_n|\theta) = \underbrace{(\theta+1)^n(T_1\ldots T_n)^\theta}_{g(T_1T_2\cdot\ldots\cdot T_n,\,\theta)} \underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{n} I_{(0,1)}(T_i)}_{h(T_1,\ldots,T_n)},
$$
and $T_1\cdot T_2\cdot \ldots \cdot T_n$ is a sufficient statistics.

Comment: @NCh: Thanks a ton. I was dumb enough to overcomplicate thing. For my curiosity, is $\prod_{i=1}^{n} = I_{(-\infty, 1)}(t_{(n)})I_{(0, \infty)}(t_{(1)})$?

Comment: @NCh: wait a minute...$T_1...T_n$ is not ONE-DIMENSIONAL, isn't it? So we actually have to rewrite this product somehow to make it become one-variable?

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^{n} = I_{(-\infty, 1)}(t_{(n)})I_{(0, \infty)}(t_{(1)})$ - it is true. 

You think $T_1...T_n$ is a vector $T_1...T_n \in\mathbb R^d$? Of what dimensions?

Comment: Nvm... I think it is in $R$. But I found another solution (maybe too powerful to handle this toy problem): consider the ratio of $f(T(\overline{x})|\theta)/f(T(\overline{y})|\theta) = (\frac{x_1\ldots x_n}{y_1\ldots y_n})^{\theta}$.This ratio does not depend on $\theta$ IFF $x_1\ldots x_n = y_1\ldots y_n$. So by theorem, $T(x) =  x_1\ldots x_n$ is a minimal (i.e, one-dimensional) sufficient statistics. This is correct, I think?

Comment: Minimal sufficient statistics does not nesessarily be one-dimensional. Say, for Uniform distribution on $[\theta,\theta+1]$ the minimal sufficient statistics is two-dimensional. Sufficient statistics $\prod T_i$ is one-dimensional simply because it is one-dimensional.

Comment: @Nch: thank you so much for your patience. It helped a lot!!